# Kendo grid columns not displaying field off of a JSON object

Tags: json, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid, defined as such:

```
$("#auditGrid").kendoGrid({
height: 650,
width: 650,
sortable: true,
filterable: true,
resizable: true, 
columns: [
     { field: "ChangeTypeDescription", title: "Change Type" },
     { field: "LevelDescription", title: "Level" },
     { field: "Site.ShortName", title: "Site", width: "100px", },
     { field: "TimeStampLocal", title: "Date", type: "date", format: "{0: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" }
]
});
```

However, the column labelled "Site" does not display anything, even when I know there should be something there. Setting the field as "Site" instead of "Site.ShortName" shows a value of [object Object], but whenever I try to display ShortName off of Site, it shows an empty column. All other columns display properly.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

The datasource schema, in case you need to see it:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
            ChangeTypeDescription: { type: "string" },
            LevelDescription: { type: "string" },
            Site: { type: "string" },
            TimeStampLocal: { type: "date" }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you please post the sample data of your datasource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to use the template functionality for achieving it, just change the column description of the field Site as follows

```
{ field: 'Site', title: 'Site', template: '#= Site.ShortName# '}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was this, along with another problem. In the datasource schema, I set Site as a type string, so the object that comes in get set as string, giving me another error when I try to get the ShortName off of the object.